# Access Thread local global variable from another thread in dynamic loaded library & C & Linux?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, shared-libraries

So I currently have some dynamic library loaded in my main program.
There are some thread local variables in the dynamic library which my main thread wants to find out the values of those local variables for each of the thread spawned.

However, as far as I know, dlopen()/dlsym()/dlclose() combination only returns the address of the variables in the current thread, but I need the variables from all the threads.

I was wondering if there is any pointers I can look up in order to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Does the term thread **local** ring a bell?

Comment: Have each thread store its TLS addresses as pointeters somewhere (e.g global array) that the main thread can access. The main thread can then dereference those pointers.

Comment: Hi, yes but the local libraries cannot be modified. I was wondering if there is anything I can do using the __tls_get_addr or other ways to manipulate the TLS variables. I have been thinking maybe a callback function but doesn't know exactly where to start look at.